# How to set bot activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am having trouble figuring out what I must do to set a custom game activity. I have tried a few different combinations of code, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'a game' }})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In discord.js, the presence can be set like this:

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.user.setActivity('a game', { type: 'PLAYING' })
})
```

Comment: I add the official documentation [DiscordJs - setActivity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`` bot.user.setActivity({ type: "PLAYING", name: `game name` }) ``

Answer (score 0):

you can set the various activities like STREAMING, PLAYING, WATCHING  and  your custom activity.This might help:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is online!')
 client.user.setActivity('a game', {type : 'STREAMING'} )
   })
```